# Stopping criteria in iterative methods for solving nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-equations, iterative-method

Is it a good criterion to stop iterative methods for solving non-linear equations, such as Newton-Raphson and good Broyden's methods, when $|x_k-x_{k-1}|<|x_k|\,reltol + abstol$ **OR** when $|f_k|<tolfun$, or should it be when $|x_k-x_{k-1}|<|x_k|\,reltol + abstol$ **AND** when $|f_k|<tolfun$?

Until now, I was using the first criterion, but recently I had a problem using the Broyden's method in a continuation algorithm: when trying to obtain the next point of the curve, $\{x_k\}$ converged to a value $x^*$ although the residual was already too big. Is this because the stopping criterion I was using was not good enough, or is it just because there might be a bifurcation at that point?

Comment: It can happen in principle that the condition on $f$ will never be satisfied, if, for example, $|f'(x_*)|u > \mathit{tolfun}$ ($u$—unit roundoff).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Kirill. I'm looking now for a practical example of this. Trying $f=K*(ln(x)-y_0)$ with $K=1e8$, a random $y0$ and $tolfun=1e-100$, Newton-Raphson succeeds. Could you please suggest me another function to try?

Comment: I just tried your example with $K=10^8, y_0=0.1$, and the root $x_0 = 1.1051709180756475$ (in double precision) has the property that $f(x_0)\approx -1.25\times 10^{-8}$, but $f(x_0+\epsilon)\approx 6.94\times 10^{-9}$, where $x_0+\epsilon$ is the next double-precision floating-point number immediately after $x_0$. So there are no such numbers for which $|f|<10^{-9}$. I think it's also possible to come up with easy polynomial examples by, e.g., taking characteristic polynomials of random integer matrices.

Comment: Thank you @Kirill, I have tried your example and Newton does not converge now if we impose $|f|<10^{-9}$. I think I am getting it. If the slope of $f(x)$ is too high at the root, it can be imposible to reach the desired tolerance since we cannot move along $x$ in a continuous way, but in jumps of value $\epsilon$, so that, when passing the root, $|f(x)|$ jumps from one value higher than $tolfun$ to another one higher that $tolfun$ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can happen in principle that the condition on $f$ will never be satisfied, if, for example, $|f'(x_*)|u>\mathit{tolfun}$, where $u$ is the unit roundoff.

When I tried your example with $K=10^8,y_0=0.1$, and the root $x_0=1.1051709180756475$ (in double precision) has the property that $f(x_0)≈−1.25×10^{−8}$, but $f(x_0+\epsilon)≈6.94×10^{−9}$, where $x_0+\epsilon$ is the next double-precision floating-point number immediately after $x_0$. So there are no such numbers for which $|f|<10^{-9}$. I think it's also possible to come up with easy polynomial examples by, e.g., taking characteristic polynomials of random integer matrices.

In general, the relationship between the residual of the equation $f(x)=0$ and the error $x-x_*$ depends on the function itself. You know that asymptotically both $f(x)$ and $x-x_*$ will converge to zero, but to derive a bound of the true error $x-x_*$ from the residual $f(x)$ requires making assumptions on $f$. If you know the value of $|f'(x_*)|$, then you know that $|x-x_*|\approx |f(x)|/|f'(x_*)|$. In the multivariate case, the inequality instead says that 
$$\|f(x)\|\|J\|^{-1} \lesssim \|x-x_*\| \lesssim \|f(x)\|\|J^{-1}\|,$$
so you need at least to know the condition of the Jacobian to convert the residual to an error estimate (see Higham's *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms*, 25.5).

All of the above is *before* you start analyzing the numerical stability of evaluating $f$ near a root. You gave an example of essentially a linear function, but for a typical more complicated function, you wouldn't be able to evaluate $f$ accurately to full machine precision near a root at all, which will also limit how small $f$ can possibly get.

---